# How to define connection timeout when executing specific SP in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, connection-timeout

I'm using express FW in node.js to connect to SQL server and execute SP.
I have a SP which executes more time than defined in the express default configuration. I get error saying: "Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms".
I would like to define a longer timeout **for this specific SP** when executing it, where can I do it ? 
Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('../../config');
const sql = require('mssql');
const db = require('../../modules/db')({
connectionString: config.connectionString
}); 


const GetData = (params) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    db.connect().then((pool) => {
        return pool.request()
            .input(<input param for the SP>), 
            .execute(<SP name>);
    }).then((data) => {
        resolve(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    }).then(() => { })
 });
};

router.use("<path>", <middleware function>, (req, res, next) => {
return GetData(req.body).then((dataResult) => {
    res.status(200).json(dataResult);
}).catch((err) => {
    next({
        details: err
    })
 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found a way of setting it (requestTimeout) in the configuration of the db connection, and after the query is being executed\failed - remove that property from the configuration - that way the default value is active again. See my code:

```
const GetData = (params) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  db.options.connectionString.requestTimeout = <dedicated value>;
  db.connect().then((pool) => {
      return pool.request()
          .input(<input param for the SP>), 
          .execute(<SP name>);
   }).then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
      delete db.options.connectionString.requestTimeout;
   }).catch((error) => {
     reject(error);
  }).then(() => { delete db.options.connectionString.requestTimeout; })
 });
};
```